# VS 2015 intern Android Emulator not starting (vmWare 10)

Tags: c#, android-emulator, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am running VS2015 CTP6 on a freshly installed and updated Windows 8.1 N x64 VM. 
[Hyper-V support is enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go8c7.png), `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"`and `vhv.enable = "TRUE"` are set to vmx-file.
When i try to run the build with a Visual Studio Emulator for Android-device VS will tell me ["starting emulator"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1Jq.png) forever. No error, no window, nothing at all.

The included AVDs (like AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova) start fine, just the new Microsoft VS Emulator for Android isn't working.

After canceling the building-process a message pops up: "Could not start emulated device 'VS Emulator....'" which will now always pop up instantly (after building) if i hit F5. So after canceling the build once VS won't even try to start the emulator again (on that project with that specific emulation-device).

In hyper-v-manager there are no computers at all. \Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android\1.0\ does not contain a XDE.exe but 2 vsemu.vhd's.

I also followed [this guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2mb7yv/you_dont_actually_have_to_launch_the_new_visual/) and tried to start the emulator as a standalone.
"pathto\XDE.exe" -vhd "pathto\vsemu.api19.vhd" which will actually start it up and displays "loading" on the emu screen but will crash because i haven't installed the Windows Phone support in VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio Emulator for Android can't be run nested inside another VM, particularly not a Hyper-V VM, because the emulator itself is a Hyper-V VM (and Hyper-V doesn't support nested VMs). See the last bullet in "Current limitations" at the end of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/introducing-visual-studio-s-emulator-for-android.aspx).

Comment: You are right. I was confused by the official download-page from VS2015 which tells me "We strongly recommend only installing this release in a virtual machine" so i thought it has to work in a VM. Genymotion isn't running in a VM either. Guess i have to wait for the final version of VS2015.

Comment: That warning (to only install in a VM) is excessively cautious. You should have your computer backed up, on general principles, but the chances of the current VS 2015 CTP 6 causing your OS to crash is very low.

Comment: You're right--that is confusing. I'll pass this feedback along. Thanks!

Comment: But the WP8 emulator works. Why would the Android emulator not work? @JohnKemnetz

Comment: @Krumelur Are you saying the WP8 emulator works when run on a Hyper-V VM? I'd be surprised to hear that.

Comment: @JohnKemnetz Want me to send you an screenshot? :-) No joking, it works. Both Parallels and VMware have supported for nested virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

My emulators disappeared (according to VS) after CTP6 update although all the images, SDKs etc. are still there.

I sorted it with a repair (control panel, programs, vs => modify.) It took many hours do just let it run.

Double check that the VM you are running on has enough memory(emulator will use a lot- and run Procmon to see what VS does and where it fails. Check event log and turn on logging for the VS instance you are using to look for cues.

"The Visual Studio Emulator for Android can't be run nested inside another VM"- is incorrect. My Windows10 VM is happily serving up the emulator for the different platforms and the same goes for Windows 8.1 & 8.

HyperV doesn't seem to be able to support quite yet (AFAIK) but there are other hypervisors you can use such as VMWare player- and from your config edits in the VM I assume you already knew that :)

I'll provide picture proof later (phone only right now so I'll have to edit typos as well later).

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking Virtual Maschine Settings did the trick for me. I was also trying to run the Android emulator by starting a debug session in VS2015 Community for a Xamarin project. VS2015 was running inside a Windows10 VM based on VMware Workstation 12 Pro hosted by Windows7 on a i7 CPU. I ran into the following error message:

"... The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone.andreas' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID ...)."

Everything worked fine after activating the following flags in the virtual machine's processor settings section:

- Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI
- Virtualize CPU performance counters
- (Preferred mode: Automatic)