# VS 2015 intern Android Emulator not starting vmWare

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

My Comment got deleted from [VS 2015 intern Android Emulator not starting (vmWare 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926199/vs-2015-intern-android-emulator-not-starting-vmware-10)

I can confirm that the Windows Phone 8 runs inside of a VMware workstation 9 instance. But the Android Emulators with Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 does not. Hyper-V can run inside of VMWare as it supports [Instruction for Hyper-V in VMware. If your processor supports Intel-VT technology][1] When i Look at the Hyper-V Manager when Android Emulator Starts the following error appears. init: Failed tp read from /dev/hw_random: No such device. . Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: I found a way to get it working. After alot of reading and searching. We do not support running in VMWare today, but the new images might work if you disable OpenGL by going to Program Files (or Program Files x86 if you're on a 64-bit machine) \ Microsoft XDE \ 10.0.0.0 \ SKUs \ Android \ xdesku.xml and deleting this line: GuestDisplayProvider = "VsEmulator.OpenGLGuestDisplay". However, without OpenGL turned on you will not be able to take advantage of many of the new features.